# Члены структуры возвращают inf. C++

Tags: c++

Класс, который содержит объект структуры `vector2d`

```
class Foo {

public:
    Foo() {
        acceleration_force = vector2d();
        //acceleration_force(); не видит конструктора вообще
        cout << "acc x: " << acceleration_force.x << " y: " << acceleration_force.y << endl;
    }
private:
    vector2d acceleration_force;
};
```

Моя структура `vector2d`

```
#ifndef VECTORS_H
#define VECTORS_H

struct vector2d {

    vector2d(float y, float x) : y(y), x(x) {}
    vector2d() : y(-1), x(0) {}

    float y, x;
};

#endif /* VECTORS_H */
```

Вывод получается `acc x: inf y: -inf`

Хотя тот же код успешно работает на [ideone](https://ideone.com/Xj2SVb)

Текст вывожу при помощи `ncurses` функцией `printw`.

---

Похоже у меня проблема с указателями и ссылками, т.к. дебагер показывает все правильно.

Функция `AddAcceleration`:

```
void AddAcceleration(vector2d direction, float value) {
    acceleration_force = (direction.normal()*value) * mass;
}
```

Функция `vector2d::normal()`

```
vector2d normal() {
    vector2d result(*this);
    result.x = result.length() / result.x;
    result.y = result.length() / result.y;
    return result;
}
```

Функция `GetForce`:

```
vector2d GetForce() {
    return acceleration_force;
}
```

Функция `vector2d::lenght`:

```
float length() {
    return sqrt(y*y+x*x);
}
```

Переменные класса `Foo`:

```
private:
    float mass;
    vector2d acceleration_force;
    float speed;
    vector2d friction;
    vector2d force;
    vector2d direction;
```

`GetMass()`, `GetSpeed()` простые геттеры.

Участок кода, который выводит на экран значения вектора:

```
foo = Foo();
foo.AddAcceleration(vector2d(-1,0), 2);
printw("%f, %f", mov.GetForce().x, mov.GetForce().y);
```

Так же, еще прошу посмотреть классы, где я перегрузил операторы `*` и `+` структуры `vector2d`. Они тоже, как я понял, не работают:

```
vector2d operator+(const vector2d& right) const {
    vector2d result(*this); // Make a copy of myself.
    result.x += right.x;
    result.y += right.y;
    return result;
}

vector2d operator*(const float right) const {
    vector2d result(*this);
    result.x *= right;
    result.y *= right;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: в студии тоже не воспроизводится, возможно запускается старая версия а не текущая?

Comment: @grundy студии нет, я на линуксе. Запускаю в `netbeans`, стандарт `c++11`, `gcc 4.8.4`. Проект очищал и перекомпилировал, не работает

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что я в студии данный код запустил и все нормально отработало, и кстати без строки _acceleration_force = vector2d();_ тоже

Comment: g++ 4.8.4, всё работает: `acc x: 0 y: -1`. Ключи компилятора?

Comment: @pinktux, `-lncurses`. Похоже у меня проблема с указателями, дебагер показывает все верно

Comment: А что "*не видит конструктора*" - всё правильно. В таком виде вызывается не конструктор (кстати, зачем? он уже вызван для переменной `acceleration_force`), а перегруженный `vector2d::operator()()`, которого нет.

Comment: @pinktux я после `java` с `c++` плаваю :) Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас тут `result.length() / result.x;` деление на ноль, отсюда и бесконечность

Comment: Код неполный. Что  такое `mass`, `lenght()`? Про передачу параметров и возврат по значению даже упоминать не буду...

Comment: @pinktux дополнил

Comment: @pavelparshin, Возможно, но по дефолтному конструктору `y = -1`, так что у `y` не может быть бесконечность. Кстати, спасибо за то, что заметили, надо исправить

Comment: И тут же получаем: `Member 'mass' was not initialized in this constructor`, `Member 'speed' was not initialized in this constructor`. Что закономерно приводит к результату `inf, -inf`.

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался в чем проблема `inf`, `-inf`.
Когда `х = 0, y = -1`, считается длина `sqrt( -1 * -1 + 0 * 0) == 1`, переменная х становится `x = 1 / x = 1 / 0 = inf`, далее длина уже считается как `sqrt ( -1 * -1 * inf * inf)`. Плюс надо было наоборот делить координату на длину вектора. И умножение на `mass` даёт `nan`, т.к. `mass` не была инициализированна